# Xcode does not select Info.plist in Nativescript app

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, info.plist

I am trying to build my Nativescript app with Xcode.

I have built a standard Nativescript Angular App, I have opened the project in xcode using the project.xcworkspace folder. When I try to select the Info.plist on the general tab in xcode, it shows the following file tree: project/project/Supporting Files/project-Info.plist.

My NativeScript project has an Info.plist file in APP_RESOURCES/IOS/.

This file looks correct.

I have no error messages. When I click on 'Choose Info.plist file...' in xcode, it lets me choose the above file, then closes the window. Then nothing happens and I can choose the file again. It fails silently.

Comment: Sorry, what you are exactly trying to do? If your modifications on the `App_Resources/iOS/info.plist` doesn't reflect, just try a clean build, CLI takes care of everything.

Comment: I am trying to build the project for the first time using xcode. I have been using sidekick, but now I would like to begin running the project through xcode as in order to publish I will need to be able to build it with xcode eventually.

Comment: You won't need Xcode still to publish, the release command will produce the IPA / Archive whichever you want to upload to AppStore or other distribution system.

Comment: You can use {NS} to publish to ios, https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-ios-apps